# In high voltage but low current measurement

Tags: high-voltage

I made some research but couldn't find my answer which fit my question well. First of all, I am looking for circuit design or a brilliant idea that can be applied a high voltage(app. 40kV). For this voltage all, I want to measure the current which max. 20 microampere. If my line goes higher than 20 microamperes I want to cut the line. In conclusion, I want to control my line with 40kV and 20 microampere.

Comment: *I want to cut the line.* Sounds easy doesn't it? However, imagine we had a switch to "cut the line", when open (line is cut) what voltage do you think will be across the switch? Where does the 40 kV come from? If it is made from a "more reasonable voltage" then maybe it can be switched off there. Voting as too broad, in case of 40 kV I expect that you at least have some implementation ideas showing that you know what it means to use 40 kV. This isn't something you can just do without a lot of experience.

Comment: I think some additional circuit will be required to assess how the 40kV can be controlled. If just a measurement is required, just a proper current sensor would be enough.

Comment: **You seriously need to re-think your plans**. 40 kv can arc 3 inch's in open dry air. You will need a custom built air driven contactor. Pardon my saying so, but I think you are in way over your head. 
Your question implies a severe lack of skill and know how. We will not likely help you with something so dangerous.

Comment: WHat's your Power source and financial budget. Any solution is easy or impossible depends on specs

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 My power supply is DC. Financial budget depends on my solution. But the solution is more important than budget. I am waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: *I am waiting for your suggestions* Well, keep waiting because I doubt any will come. At 40 kV it isn't a case of "do this and then do that" like would be the case with a 9V battery powering a blinking circuit. What's the worst that can happen in a 9 V circuit: the battery might deplete. What's the worst that can happen in a 40 kV circuit: **you die**.

Comment: Sounds like he expects it to cost no more than a flashbulb circuit

Comment: **trivial solution**: An opto isolated relay board common cheap online.  Ground return side high voltage DC current sense into a 2000mV/20 uA =100kohm resistor with optional Filter cap e.g. 0.1u to 74HCT74 TTL D-FF Turn OFF to  Opto Current RESET=off and power on Reset , SET to turn On. <$10

Answer (score 2):

20 microamperes is quite low, combined with high voltage... I would add a resistor and measure the voltage on it(Ohm's law) example if you have a 100k resistor, the voltage of it will be 2V when your current is 20 microamperes. So you can make a circuit that triggers with 2V and getting a resistor rated for 40kV could be expensive, I still think it is the best solution. (even if it is unlikely you will apply the 40kV to it, it is better if it is rated for it)

*The switch will be a whole other issue that you need to solve on your own, it is not easy to open 40kV, you need to do a lot of research on that end.*

edit: try to post a schematic of your circuit if you can, with these kinds of voltages you want to avoid contact with it as much as you can, seeing the schematic maybe there is a method to avoid contact with the 40kV entirely.

you might think the comments are over doing it, but even if you are certain of everything you are doing it is not dumb to remind you that this is *deadly*. Be careful.

Comment: +1 for warning the OP how dangerous 40 kv is.

Comment: Coincidentally I read this after my comment and is essentially the same solution (+1) good solution to kill AC input power not 40kV direct . Except I used 100k on HVDC return side for sensing. Your load is the hiV BDV rated circuit, I presume he understands arcs and Partial Discharge. Impulses. If not then a 100MHz 1 turn current sensor is needed for high speed impulse sensing into 50 Ohm line.

Comment: well, I assume he is using a transformer with a lot of turns so even measuring the current on the low end is possible, or he is using some sort of multiplicating circuit like cockroft walton or marx, still in those cases I would avoid doing the measurement on the high side if I can. I think I will edit this info in